# Oracle SQL - Why this query has full table scan?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

I've got a problem with this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM customer_table PARTITION (p25062014)
 WHERE (   customer_table.username NOT IN ('user1','user2','user3')
        OR customer_table.username IS NULL
       )
   AND (customer_table.ip NOT IN ('ip1','ip2','ip3') OR customer_table.ip IS NULL
       )
   AND (   customer_table."ACCOUNT DEVICE ID" NOT IN ('deviceId1','deviceId2','deviceId3')
        OR customer_table."ACCOUNT DEVICE ID" IS NULL
       )
```

Even if I've created the indexes on this table for these fields, I've got a "Table Access Full" on the table:

```
CREATE INDEX customer_table_USERNAME ON customer_table
(USERNAME)

CREATE INDEX customer_table_DEVICE_ID ON customer_table
("ACCOUNT DEVICE ID")

CREATE INDEX customer_table_IP ON customer_table
(IP)
```

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 2  Bytes: 965  Cardinality: 1       
    2 PARTITION RANGE SINGLE  Cost: 2  Bytes: 965  Cardinality: 1  Partition #: 1  Partitions accessed #21  
        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE customer_table Cost: 2  Bytes: 965  Cardinality: 1  Partition #: 2  Partitions accessed #21
```

How I can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: If your table has only one row ("Cardinality = 1"), then a full table scan is the most efficient method for accessing the data for almost any query I can think of.

Comment: Hi Gordon, this table is almost empty for now, but soon it will contains about 2 millions of record for every partition.

Comment: Does it need to be fixed? What actual issue are you facing? Null values aren't indexed and `not in` usually can't use an index efficiently, so a full table (or partition) scan may appropriate - even if you do have more than one row. Are your statistics up to date? Oracle will choose a plan based on the statistics and the state it thinks the table is in when the query is parsed; not on your projected growth, which it knows nothing about.

Comment: @Fabio . . . When you add more data to the table -- and be sure the statistics are updated -- then Oracle will choose a better execution plan.

Comment: And how I can be sure that Oracle updates the statistics? I also can change the query in order to have better performance, but I can't imagine a different query

Comment: Oracle never creates an index entry where all columns in the entry are NULL. You have 3 indexes all on a single column and, as your where clause suggest, any or all can be null.  As the where clause want rows where any/all are NULLs then none of them can be used. Also @ammoQ is correct. Indexes (even in books) are generally good for finding things, not `NOT` finding things.

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN` where clauses usually do not use indexes, since there is not much to gain from the index. Read the details [here](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/indexes-and-not-equal-not-now-john/). Though that blog explains why indexes are ignored for the "not eqals" comparision, the same is valid also for `NOT IN`.

Comment: And how I can be sure that Oracle updates the statistics? I also can change the query in order to have better performance, but I can't imagine a different query

Comment: `dbms_stat.gather_table_stats` can be used to keep the statistics up-to-date (see http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_stats_gather_table_stats.htm ), but that won't make the index more useful. Probably the best you can do is to reduce the column list in the select (not `SELECT *` if you don't need that data) and create a spawning index that includes all columns in the select list and all columns used in the where clause. This allows Oracle to do a full index scan instead of a full table scan and can be significantely faster.

Comment: ok, I will specify the column list instead of <pre>SELECT *</pre> but how I can create the <pre>spawning index that includes all columns in the select list and all columns used in the where clause</pre>?

The where clause is already present, the select list is <pre>TIMESTAMP, CHANNEL, TDE, MESSAGE, SERVICE ,OFFER</pre>

Comment: if your query is `select a,b,c from mytable where d not in (1,2) and e not in (3,4)`, the index would be `create index i_mytable on mytable(d,e,a,b,c)` so it can be used for both checking the where condition and gathering the results (so Oracle doesn't have to read the table). The order of the columns probably doesn't make much difference in this example, since a full index scan is a full index scan no matter which order the columns are. But don't include all columns from the table in the index, that would nullify its usefulness!

Comment: Thanks, I'm improving my query a lot!
But I can't understand why this query isin full table scan:

<pre>UPDATE relation_customer
   SET "OUTPUT SISTEM" = '',
       "ELAB TIME" = ''
 WHERE KEY1 = ''
   AND KEY2 = ''
   AND KEY3 = ''
   
   
   CREATE INDEX usertalend.INDEX_QUERY_15 ON relation_customer
("OUTPUT SISTEM",
       "ELAB TIME", KEY1,
       KEY2, KEY3" );</pre>
I've seen that if I don't include "ELAB TIME" which is a number field on db the access is not in full table scan, while if I incluse this field it is full.

Comment: It's really hard to read that way, maybe you want to make that another question?